# Unknown provider: $animateCssProvider <- $animateCss <- $uibModalStack <- $uibModal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

If I update my angular version to higher version I am sure it will work, but I am more depended on `1.3.20` version of angular.

I tried `angular-bootstrap` version from `1.1` to the `latest`, nothing works with the `1.3.20`. All I get is unknown provider.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8TynLlehbEoJF4HY9o0S?p=preview

This plunkr code works when you comment line 9 & uncomment line 10.

But it works nicely when 1.3.20's ngAnimate & angular version with `angular-bootstrap` version 0.14.3 which is very old code.

How can I fix this issue without upgrading angular version?

If I can add `$animateCss` provider explicitly does it work? but I doubt does it impact any other code.

I don't want to use angular-bootstrap's 0.14.3 since it is outdated.

Comment: what is `animate.js` file?

Comment: I thought of patching $animateCss provider but I am not clear on how to make it work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation for Angular Bootstrap:

> UI Bootstrap 1.0 and higher requires Angular 1.4.x or higher and it has been tested with Angular 1.4.8
>
> UI Bootstrap 0.14.3 is the last version that supports Angular 1.3.x

You must downgrade or upgrade one or the other. You have no other option.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code Please Check

it is working fine now

http://plnkr.co/edit/JTnaTm8vOMOVkouaEcde?p=preview

```
Previously you used older animate version I think..
```

Comment: I don't see your changes

Comment: Ah! I dont want to update angular/angular-animate to 1.4 :(

Comment: I need to patch the `$animateCss`

Comment: I meant angular & angular-animate as well.